# Join nested JSON dataframe and another dataframe

Tags: json, pandas, join

I am trying to join a dataframe1 generated by the JSON with dataframe2 using the field order_id, then assign the "status" from dataframe2 to the "status" of dataframe1. Anyone knows how to do this. Many thanks for your help.

dataframe1

```
[{
        "client_id": 1,
        "name": "Test01",
        "olist": [{
            "order_id": 10000,
            "order_dt_tm": "2012-12-01",
            "status": ""   <== use "status" from dataframe2 to populate this field
        },
        {
            "order_id": 10000,
            "order_dt_tm": "2012-12-01",
            "status": ""
        }
        ]    
    },
    {
        "client_id": 2,
        "name": "Test02",
        "olist": [{
            "order_id": 10002,
            "order_dt_tm": "2012-12-01",
            "status": ""
        },
        {
            "order_id": 10003,
            "order_dt_tm": "2012-12-01",
            "status": ""
        }
        ]    
    }
]
```

dataframe2

```
order_id     status
10002        "Delivered"
10001        "Ordered"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your raw dataset as a json string:

```py
d = """[{
        "client_id": 1,
        "name": "Test01",
        "olist": [{
            "order_id": 10000,
            "order_dt_tm": "2012-12-01",
            "status": ""
        },
        {
            "order_id": 10000,
            "order_dt_tm": "2012-12-01",
            "status": ""
        }
        ]    
    },
    {
        "client_id": 2,
        "name": "Test02",
        "olist": [{
            "order_id": 10002,
            "order_dt_tm": "2012-12-01",
            "status": ""
        },
        {
            "order_id": 10003,
            "order_dt_tm": "2012-12-01",
            "status": ""
        }
        ]    
    }
]"""
```

Firstly, I would load it as json:

```py
import json
data = json.loads(d)
```

Then, I would turn it into a Pandas dataframe, notice that I remove **status** field as it will be populated by the join step :

```py
df1 = pd.json_normalize(data, 'olist')[['order_id', 'order_dt_tm']]
```

Then, from the second dataframe sample, I would do a left join using merge function:

```py
data = {'order_id':[10002, 10001],'status':['Delivered', 'Ordered']}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data)
result = df1.merge(df2, on='order_id', how='left')
```

Good luck

**UPDATE**

```py
# JSON to Dataframe
df1 = pd.json_normalize(data)

# Sub JSON to dataframe
df1['sub_df'] = df1['olist'].apply(lambda x: pd.json_normalize(x).drop('status', axis=1))

# Build second dataframe
data2 = {'order_id':[10002, 10001],'status':['Delivered', 'Ordered']}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)

# Populates status in sub dataframes
df1['sub_df'] = df1['sub_df'].apply(lambda x: x.merge(df2, on='order_id', how='left').fillna(''))

# Sub dataframes back to JSON

def back_to_json_str(df):
    # turns a df back to string json
    return str(df.to_json(orient="records", indent=4))
    
df1['olist'] = df1['sub_df'].apply(lambda x: back_to_json_str(x))

# Global DF back to JSON string
parsed = str(df1.drop('sub_df', axis=1).to_json(orient="records", indent=4))
parsed = parsed.replace(r'\n', '\n')
parsed = parsed.replace(r'\"', '\"')

# Print result
print(parsed)
```

**UPDATE 2**
here is a way to add index colum to a dataframe:

```py
df1['index'] = [e for e in range(df1.shape[0])]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But, after joining successfully, May I know how populate the values of the field "status" back to original JSON dataframe. Thanks.

Comment: you can do ```df1 = df1.merge(df2, on='order_id', how='left')```

Comment: But I want to populate the value of status back the original json object.
{
            "order_id": 10003,
            "order_dt_tm": "2012-12-01",
            "status": "ordered"     <========== the value comes from the left-joined dataframe.
        }

Comment: Please see my update. Notice there is only order 10002 that has a status thanks to the data sample.

Comment: It works. Many thanks. I just got another question. When we normalize the json object, is it possible to add 2 index fields. One is the index of array data, the other is the index of array olist. Something is like below:
   order_id order_dt_tm status client_id name index1 index2
0 10000 2012-12-01          1         Test01   0      0
1 10001 2012-12-01          1         Test01   0      1
2 10002 2012-12-01          2         Test02   1      0
3 10003 2012-12-01          2         Test02   1      1

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Please see UPDATE 2, its a way to add an index to a dataframe

Comment: Many thanks for your help. I wonder if you could help me improve the performance of my code below.

Answer (score 0):

This is my code assigning title values from a dataframe back to the JSON object. The assignment operation takes a bit time if the number records in the JSON object is 100000. Anyone knows how to improve the performance of this code. Many thanks.

```
import json
import random
import pandas as pd
import pydash as _

data = [{"pid":1,"name":"Test1","title":""},{"pid":2,"name":"Test2","title":""}] # 5000 records

# dataframe1
df = pd.json_normalize(data)

# dataframe2
pid = [x for x in range(1, 5000)]
title_set = ["Boss", "CEO", "CFO", "PMO", "Team Lead"]
titles = [title_set[random.randrange(0, 5)] for x in range(1, 5000)]
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'pid': pid, 'title': titles})

#left join dataframe1 and dataframe2
df3 = df.merge(df2, on='pid', how='left')

#assign title values from dataframe back to the json object
for row in df3.iterrows():
    idx = _.find_index(data, lambda x: x['pid'] == row[1]['pid'])
    data[idx]['title'] = row[1]['title_y']

print(data)
```